# Invert a Quine!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, quine

We all know what a [quine](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4877/what-counts-as-a-proper-quine?) is.  An *inverted* quine is a non-empty program that prints the inverse of its source code without reading its source code, and consists solely of printable-ASCII characters (space through `~`).

Here, “inverse of the source code” means the following: the output of your program must contain each printable ASCII character **(m − c)** times, where **c** is the number of times said character occurs in your code, and **m** is the maximum number of times any character is repeated in your code.

(In other words: **your code** + **your output** = permutation of **m** times all of printable-ASCII.)

For example, if your program is `12345`, then **m = 1**, and you should output any permutation of this string:

```
 !"#$%&'()*+,-./06789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

If your program is `AAB`, then **m = 2**, and you should output any permutation of:

```
  !!""##$$%%&&''(())**++,,--..//00112233445566778899::;;<<==>>??@@BCCDDEEFFGHHIIJJKKLLMMNNOOPPQQRRSSTTUUVVWWXXYYZZ[[\\]]^^__``aabbccddeeffgghhiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~
```

Note how there are two missing `A`s, and one missing `B`.

Although a program that contains all the printable ASCII characters and outputs nothing is a valid inverse quine (satisfying **m = 1**), such an answer would not be very competitive, given its length.

You are to write a program that is an inverted quine, as described in the above paragraph.  As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest program in bytes will win. Good luck!

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14068/69331)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino This contains several additional conditions that would invalidate quite a few submissions, including the winning one.  In my opinion, it isn't a dupe.

Comment: Space, tab and newline?

Comment: You should highlight the `duplicated for every repeated character in the source code` it makes all the difference in the challenge

Comment: Could you give an example of the inverse where multiple characters are repeated (and multiple times)? Say, `11234512345`?

Comment: If I understand the challenge correctly, it indeed isn't a dupe. But you should clarify the challenge and add more examples. I think I understand what you mean, but I'm not entirely sure. Could you check my comments on the [Java answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145666/invert-a-quine#comment356453_145671) and [QBIC answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145666/invert-a-quine#comment356462_145685) to see if I understand it?

Comment: How is this a duplicate? Related, yes. Duplicate, no! It's *way* more difficult in languages where you have to have duplicate characters. Note that you can't just duplicate a string either, since the number of characters you must remove from each string is varying.

Comment: @StewieGriffin I would VTC this as "unclear" rather than a "dupe" because (nearly) every answer has a comment trying to figure out what `duplicated for every repeated character in the source code` means or if the submission is valid for that criterion, because the OP hasn't addressed quite a few of the questions here.

Comment: I've voted to close as unclear too.

Comment: @StewieGriffin, no, spaces, tabs and newlines are not technically included in printable-ascii, and as such, are banned.

Comment: You should specify what happens if the code is `aabb`, and `aaabbc`.Is the following correct, assuming the printable characters only contain `abcd`? The output from `aabb` should be `cdcd`, and the output for `aaabbc` should be `cdbcd`. Can you confirm or refute this, and if so, provide the correct answer?

Comment: My take on it: your output must contain each printable ASCII character `m-x` times, where `x` is the frequency of that character in your code, and `m` is the maximum frequency of _any_ character in your source code.

Comment: @Lynn exactly.  I'm having trouble putting that into words, but if you want to edit your explanation in to the question, that'd be great.

Comment: @Gryphon I’ve edited your question to explain the question as it’s clear to me, and voted to reopen — could you check if I got it right?

Answer (score 7):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), <s>221</s> 207 bytes

Includes +1 for `-A`

```
(((((((()()()()){}){}()){}){})()){}{}){({}[()]<((((((()()()()){}){}){})<>[()()()])[()])((((()()()){})){}{})<>((()()()()){}){({}[()]<(({})())>)}{}({}()())<>{{({}<>[()]<(({})())><>)}{}<>(({}())()())<>}<>>)}{}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/XwMKNCFQs7oWiGA0RADE1KiujdbQjLXBphqEbOyiIUKxmiB1mghVIFmIITZ2aDoRhkKsstMEKtMAWQ/k2NhVgxSADUZSYgNWBDIK7EyoUqAAWPz///@6jgA)

```
# Push 206 (the number of times to duplicate the output)
(((((((()()()()){}){}()){}){})()){}{})

# For 0 to 206
{({}[()]<

    # Push 32 on this stack and 18, 28 and 29 to the other
    # 18, 28 and 29 are the distances between the sets of braces 
    ((((((()()()()){}){}){})<>[()()()])[()])((((()()()){})){}{})<>

    # For 0 to 8
    ((()()()()){}){({}[()]<

        # Push TOS, TOS + 1
        (({})())

    # end For 0 to 8
    >)}{}

    # Push TOS + 2 
    # skips '(' and ')'
    ({}()())

    # For each value on the off stack (18, 28, 28)
    <>{

        # For 0 to that number
        {({}<>[()]<

            # Push TOS, TOS + 1
            (({})())

        # End for 0 to that number
        ><>)}{}

        # Push TOS + 1, TOS + 3 (skips this set of braces)
        <>(({}())()())<>

    # End for each value on the off stack (18, 28, 28)
    }<>

 # End for 0 to 206
 >)}{}
```

Comment: I think you should only remove `[` five times, not all times. Note that `2` is only removed once in the example. The challenge is a bit confusing though.

Comment: Interesting how this is drastically shorter than the standard quine. `+1` :)

Comment: This is really lame, and significantly less interesting than your answer, but technically, [`!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~`](https://tio.run/##SypKzMzTTctJzP7/X0FRSVlFVU1dQ1NLW0dXT9/A0MjYxNTM3MLSytrG1s7ewdHJ2cXVzd3D08vbx9fPPyAwKDgkNCw8IjIqOiY2Lj4hMSk5JTUtPSMzKzsnNy@/oLCouKS0rLyisqq6prbu/38A "Brain-Flak – Try It Online") would get a better score :/

Answer (score 6):

### [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 17 bytes

```
{s95c+'|,32>\-}_~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85KzP3/v7rY0jRZW71Gx9jILka3Nr7u/38A)

Prints

```
 !"#$%&()*./014678:;<=?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^`abdefghijklmnopqrtuvwxyz
```

#### Explanation

The goal was to modify the standard quine

```
{"_~"}_~
```

such that no character is repeated in the program. The reason for this is that CJam has a set different operator which we can use to remove characters from the printable ASCII range, but it doesn't take number of occurrences into account. Implementing that by hand would probably be longer, so I needed to make sure that every character appears only once and we don't have to worry about occurrences.

```
{      e# Quine framework. Executes the block while leaving another copy of the
       e# block on the stack.
  s    e#   Stringify the block, giving us "{s95c+'|,32>\-}".
  95c  e#   Convert 95 to a character, which gives us '_' without repeating
       e#   it in the source code.
  +    e#   Append it to the string. We don't need to worry about '~', we'll just
       e#   leave it out of the printable ASCII range to begin with.
  '|,  e#   Get a character range from the null byte up to '{'. This omits "|}~",
       e#   but those are in the program anyway, it doesn't matter.
  32>  e#   Discard the unprintable characters.
  \-   e#   Subtract the source string from the printable ASCII range.
}_~
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 83 bytes

```python
print(~2/8,6>9)#!"$%&'*+14:;<=?@ABCDEGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`bcdfghjkmoquvwxyz{|}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69Eo85I30LHzM5SU1lRSUVVTV1L29DEytrG1t7B0cnZxdXdw9PL28fXzz8gMCg4JDQsPCIyKjomNi4@ISk5JS09Iys7N7@wtKy8orKquqb2/38A)

Prints `-0.375 False`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>95</s> <s>61</s> 60 bytes (not 58 b/c I dislike that one)

```
A?9L<J, !"'#$%&()*+-./:;=>@BCDEFGHIKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`{|}~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/f0d7Sx8ZLR0FRSV1ZRVVNQ1NLW1dP38ra1s7BydnF1c3dw9Pb188/IDAoOCQ0LDwiMio6JjYuPqG6prbu/38A)

Old answer invalidated by "only-ASCII characters", [a lot of commands aren't valid here.](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/info.txt)

It prints `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz012345678` one time as there are no duplicated characters.

---

## Version with `BCDEFGHIKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` removed:

*Work in progress... I think ~60 bytes is as low as you get without non-ASCII characters in 05AB1E..*

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 58 bytes

```
T5+FA'uK?Au"ADLJFKST"SK?9L<5KJ?} !#$%&()*>-./:;=@[]^_`{|~\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/xFTbzVG91NvesVTJ0cXHy807OEQp2Nve0sfG1NvLvlZBUVlFVU1DU8tOV0/fytrWITo2Lj6huqYu5v9/AA)

Prints the output x12 due to the repeated characters:

```
['""', '55', '???', 'AAA', 'FF', 'JJ', 'KKKK', 'LL', 'SS', 'TT', 'uu']
```

It also doesn't terminate quite correctly, working on that now...

---

Invalid old answers (due to non-ASCII characters) have been removed, see edit history.

Comment: "An inverted quine is a non-empty program that prints the inverse of its source code without reading its source code, *and consists solely of printable-ascii characters*." I was working on an 05AB1E answer, too, until I noticed this.

Comment: @KSmarts fixed at a cost of 76 bytes.

Comment: Typically, in a code-golf challenge, one would expect 05AB1E to do a *little* better than, "beats Java".

Comment: @KSmarts *shrug* if you don't let esolangs easily compete by definition, you deserve a sarcastic esolang answer :P.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>106</s> <s>99</s> 190 bytes

```
class i {/*{}!"#$%&'()+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`bdefghjkmnopqrtuvwxyz|~!"#$%&'()+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`claibdefghjkmnopqrtuvwxyz|~*/}
```

Comment: You can probably golf it by removing the space in `i {` because you already have a space

Comment: I believe that every character must occur the same number of times for this to be valid

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the challenge completely, but isn't just ``class i{/*!"#$%&'()+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`bdefghjkmnopqrtuvwxyz|~*/}`` enough? It contains all printable-ASCII in it's source code, and outputs nothing. The part "_duplicated for every repeated character in the source code_" applies to the output, so even though `s` is duplicated in `class` and `*` and `/` are duplicated due to `/* */`, outputting four times nothing is still nothing.

Comment: Also, if I'm indeed correct, you can also golf it to: ``interface Z{}//!"#$%&'()*+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY[\]^_`bdghjklmopqsuvwxyz|~`` (**97 bytes**)

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript (ES6), <s>103</s> 101 bytes

```
_=>` !"#$%&'()*+,-.0123456789:;<?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~`//_=>\\
```

**Old solution (103 bytes using `alert`)**

```
alert;;alert`\ \!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_bcdfghijkmnopqsuvwxyz{|}~`
```

**Old (invalid) solution (96 bytes)**

```
alert()// !"#$%&'*+,-.0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`bcdfghijkmnopqsuvwxyz{|}~
```

Comment: You have two `//`, which means you must output the printable characters, with one `/` removed. (I think)

Comment: @StewieGriffin Fixed